# transferring two dimensional array with attributes into an another page

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a 2 dimensional array which is like that;

```
$results[$i][$j]->title;
$results[$i][$j]->snippet;
$results[$i][$j]->link;
```

It is full with values. I have to use this variable with its values into a different page.
I try it with session but it gives errors.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of errors did you get??

Comment: How can we tell you how to solve it if we don't know what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try serialize()'ing it before placing it in session, then unserialize()'ing it on the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to serialize the object within a session (as previously suggested) then remember that the member functions __sleep and __wakeup will automatically be called. Moreover, **you will need to ensure that the constructor of the object's class is available on the subsequent page**. (This is a very common wall people run hit when trying to pass objects vis $_SESSION.)

http://php.net/function.serialize

See also:

http://php.net/language.oop5.serialization

Had you considered just extracting the object attributes you need and storing them as scalar values in an array? This would be easily storable via $_SESSION and would not require additional consideration.

Answer (score 3):

first page :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fancy array'] = array("foo"=>array("b","a","r"));
```

Second page :

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['fancy array']);
```

Works for me :]

Comment: and just to note, always keep session_start(); in the top of your php file, before header() commands and the like.

Comment: you can put session_start() after a header() call. headers aren't considered "output". session_start() is simply a wrapper around what boils down to `unserialize/load the session file, setcookie()`, and setcookie itself uses a header() call.

Answer (score 1):

on page1, after declaration of `$results` var, before output of any kind. (before `<html>`)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['results'] = $results;
```

On page2:

```
session_start();
$results = $_SESSION['results'];
```

Comment: Heh, giving you a +1 since you answered about the same time as me (10 sec difference) and almost same answer :D